How to Populate a ChoiceMenu with Multiple Items from a Defined List
I'm trying to create a form in where a dropdown menu (ComboBox) is populated with multiple items from a predefined list. However, when I use the definition of the list, the ComboBox only shows a single choice instead of all the items in the list.

Here's a my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% list of choices
\def\ListIssuers{{Barclays plc},{BNP Paribas},{CACIB},{Citi},{HSBC},{Natixis},{Société Générale}}
%\def\ListIssuers{Barclays plc,BNP Paribas,CACIB,Citi,HSBC,Natixis,Société Générale}

\begin{document}


\begin{Form}
  \ChoiceMenu[
    combo,
    name=emetteur,
    width=\linewidth
  ]{}{\ListIssuers}
\end{Form}

\end{document}

In the above example, \ListIssuers is supposed to provide multiple items for the dropdown, but instead, the ComboBox shows only one option containing the entire list as a single string.
How can I correctly define and use a list so that each item appears as a separate choice in the ComboBox?

hyperref doesn't expand the list. But you could write a wrapper command
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\ListIssuers{{Barclays plc},{BNP Paribas},{CACIB},{Citi},{HSBC},{Natixis},{Société Générale}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn\jet_choice_menu:nn #1#2
 {
   \ChoiceMenu[combo,name=#1,width=\linewidth]{}{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jet_choice_menu:nn {no}

\NewDocumentCommand\ChoiceMenuFromList{mm}
 { \jet_choice_menu:no {#1}{#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Form

\ChoiceMenuFromList{emetteur}{\ListIssuers}

\end{document}


